# SET one var with 2 elements in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I only want to get the COUNT(page_ID) value as @current_rank, but I am forced to use MAX(rating_time) more because I can have several records of "page_ID" respecting the WHERE clause but at different date ("rating_time").

And among these potential multiple page_ID records, I want the most recent.

```
SET @current_rank = (SELECT COUNT(page_ID), MAX(rating_time)
    FROM ranks_update
    WHERE ranking_ID = NEW.ranking_ID
        AND page_ID <> NEW.page_ID 
        AND current_sum_vote >= @current_sum_vote
        AND rating_time >= ( *** a subquery *** ) 
    GROUP BY page_ID);
```

PS: I use triggers in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is (please correct me if i'm wrong) :

```
SELECT COUNT(page_ID)
    FROM (
    SELECT page_ID, MAX(rating_time)
    FROM ranks_update
    WHERE ranking_ID = NEW.ranking_ID
        AND page_ID <> NEW.page_ID 
        AND current_sum_vote >= @current_sum_vote
        AND rating_time >= (*** a subquery ***) 
    GROUP BY page_ID
    ) ru
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT @current_rank = COUNT(page_ID), @max_rating = MAX(rating_time)
    FROM ranks_update
    WHERE ranking_ID = NEW.ranking_ID
        AND page_ID <> NEW.page_ID 
        AND current_sum_vote >= @current_sum_vote
    GROUP BY page_ID;
```

Comment: MySql error : #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of having MAX function there is to filter the records, you would rather put in where clause in a subquery. Something like below:

```
SET @current_rank = (SELECT COUNT(page_ID)
FROM ranks_update
WHERE ranking_ID = NEW.ranking_ID
    AND page_ID <> NEW.page_ID 
    AND current_sum_vote >= @current_sum_vote
    AND rating_time in 
    (select MAX(rating_time) from ranks_update as ru where ru.page_ID = NEW.page_ID)
GROUP BY page_ID);
```

Comment: Actually I'm already using a subquery on rating_time in the WHERE clause, I updated the first post. Does it change your answer ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but what I understand from your description is that `MAX(rating_time)` is only added to force to get the maximum rating time and there is no reason to select it. That's why I didn't put is part of my select query. If what I explained above is the case, then there is no need to actually select `MAX(rating_time)`. You could use it as just a filter in your where clause. But if your @current_rank is a data (two-column record-set) you do need `MAX(rating_time)` and my query shall be changed.